# Error deploy Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, deployment, sdk

I start to develop on windows phone.
I installed SDK8.0 and visual studio 2013
I create project and try to run it and it does not work.
I try different emulator on visual but always the same error.

'Error to deploy" or "xde.exe stop"
What is the problem ? Bad sdk, bad emulator ?? , bad installation of anything else ?

Some suggestions ?

PS:  i reboot pc and visual and same error too.

Pic to see my environnement
http://hpics.li/c2d2fca

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows are you running? Is your dev environment in a VM or is it a physical machine?

This error is typically related to Hyper-V configuration issues. You can view Hyper-V system requirements [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V#System_requirements); if your machine does not meet these requirements you will be unable to use the Windows Phone Emulator.